# How to update youtube initialVideoId in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, android-youtube-api

I am using [this package](https://pub.dev/packages/youtube_player_flutter) to show videos,

And I am trying to update `initialVideoId` on list of videos (similar to yourube app, there is list of videos under player and you update player with tapped video) but it does not reload player with new id.

`code`

```
controllerFunc(String initVid) {
    setState(() {
      _controller =  YoutubePlayerController(
        initialVideoId: initVid,  // <-- trying to update this value
        flags: const YoutubePlayerFlags(
          mute: false,
          autoPlay: false,
          disableDragSeek: false,
          loop: false,
          isLive: false,
          forceHD: false,
          enableCaption: true,
        ),
      )..addListener(listener);
      _videoMetaData = const YoutubeMetaData();
      yPlayer();
    });
 }
```

and I update the `initialVideoId` on ListTile tap function like:

```
return ListTile(
  onTap: () {
    setState(() {
      controllerFunc(videosList[index]);
    });
  },
  title: ....,
);
```

but it does not load new video in player.

**Any suggestions?**

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
setState(() {
   _controller.load( YoutubePlayer.convertUrlToId(<MY VIDEO URL>),startAt:0);
   _controller.play();
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Only change `YoutubePlayerController(initialVideoId: initVid...)` by
`YoutubePlayerController.fromVideoId(videoId: initVid...)`